# regex query to get all matches for a path

Tags: regex

Yep - another noob regex query, which I can't seem to get.

I'm trying to get all matches for the string `foo.mydomain.com/` or `foo.mydomain.com:1234/` or `foo.mydomain.com:<random port>/` but any other paths do not match, ie. `foo.mydomain.com/bar` or `foo.mydomain.com/bar/pewpew`

I tried to use: `foo.mydomain.com(.*)/$`
(which starts with anything, then `foo.mydomain.com`, then any thing after that until a slash, then end. (This search query is anchored to the end of the line.)

But that doesn't work. It doesn't match when I pass in `foo.mydomain.com:1234` but it correct says `foo.mydomain.com/bar/pewpew` is not a match (as expected).

Comment: What about `foo.mydomain.com` (no trailing slash)--should it match?

Comment: Because it's a good habit to get into... escape the '.'s in your domain. Also, it helps to verbalise what you're hoping to match, quite often the regex follows easily (if you can remember the syntax). In this case: match the domain, optionally followed by a port specifier, optionally followed by a slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^foo\.mydomain\.com(?::\d+)?/?$
```

- `^` : Start anchor
- `\.` : `.` is a meta char..to match a
  literal `.` you need to escape it with `\`
- `(?:)` : grouping
- `\d` : A single digit
- `\d+` : one or more digits
- `?` : makes the previous pattern optional
- `$` : End anchor

Comment: Assuming PCRE - Perl-compatible regular expressions.  Drop the '?:' and it is a POSIX ERE (extended regular expression).  (Also, to match the port number without the trailing slash, you need '/?' before the '$'.)

Comment: @Purne.Krome: The regex would not match **foo.mydomain.com/bar**, are you sure checked it correctly ?

Comment: yep i did. it was another route in my rewriter that is fraking things. I deleted my comment before u replied, hoping u wouldn't see it :P *blush*

Answer (score 0):

```
foo\.mydomain\.com(:\d{1,5})?/\s*$
```

Try this one.

Comment: @Pure. : oops. 0 - 65535. Losing my mind... one digit at a time. Fixed. Thanks!