# Need help with this Regex + UrlRewriter.NET please :)

Tags: regex, urlrewriter.net, urlrewriter

[Previously, on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627074/can-somone-help-fix-up-my-simple-regex-query-please) ...

> *(Summarized)*
>
> I need to capture all requests, for a
> particluar subdomain .. and rewrite
> their destination.

Now, the trick to determining the host via **regex** was **solved**.

Now, i need to make sure all requests to the root index page is rewritten, but i can't figure out the correct regex to find the 'homepage' / website root.

this is what i have....

```
<if header="HTTP_HOST" match="^foo\.mydomain\.com\.au(?::\d+)?/?$">
    <!-- snip some other rewrites, eg./buying/product -> ~/Pages/Foo/Bar.aspx -->
    <rewrite url="^/$" to="~/Pages/SomeWeirdFolder/Home.aspx" processing="stop"/>
</if>
```

Now if one of the rewrites were not found, then it falls through and continues.

So .. can anyone please help?

#### UPDATE

I've also tried `"^$"`, `"^~/$"`, `"^~?/?$"` ... with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<rewrite url="^/?$" to="~/Pages/SomeWeirdFolder/Home.aspx" processing="stop"/>
<!-- -----------^ -->
```

Comment: nope. tried that also. (ie. optional root folder with start and end anchors). I'll update my original post with my other attempts...

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you are trying to match. If the text that you are matching only contains "/" then what you have should match (unless you need to escape /, like /). However if what you are trying to replace is the leading "/", as in /foo/bar/ with ~/MyPath/foo/bar then we need to account for the characters after the first "/"

Comment: I'm trying to match the root url which rewriter is trying to goto.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.

The root directory of the site is noit '/', is was the file the default document is being set to .. in this case '/default.aspx'

after that, it all worked :)